# How to uninstall cooliris from google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, uninstall

How to uninstall cooliris from google chrome? Any suggestion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### First:

[image]

### Second:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Tools menu.

   [image]
2. Select Extensions.
3. Click Uninstall for the extension you'd like to completely remove.

From [Google Chrome Help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113907).